# Continous loop to check if a list item has changed, javascript

Tags: javascript, caml-query, html, time-out

I'm trying to create a function that runs every 5 seconds to check if a list item (setting) has changed. This will then reload the page (if setting is true) and sets the setting to false.

Here's what I currently have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function loopScript(){
    setInterval(checkSetting, 5000);
}
function checkSetting() {
 var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Biz.WebPartSettings');
 var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Query> \
   <Where> \
         <Eq> \
            <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
            <Value Type='Text'>PS-ImageSliderRefresh-ImageSlider</Value> \
         </Eq> \
   </Where> \
</Query>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    //console.log(oListItem.get_fieldValues());  
        if(oListItem.get_item('Setting_x0020_Value') == 'Yes'){
            oListItem.set_item('Setting_x0020_Value', 'No');
                console.log(oListItem.get_fieldValues());  
                oListItem.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailure));

        }
    }
    //alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request Failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
function onQuerySuccess(sender, args){
alert('Setting changed');
location.reload(true);
}
function onQueryFailure(sender, args) {

    alert('Request Failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:loopScript();">
</body>
</html>

The error I currently have is that **loopScript() is undefined** when I have given a definition.
```

The reason behind this is that the page content may have changed but won't be accessible to the user to perform a refresh.
Feel free to ask for more info if needed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your string literal for `set_viewXml`. You need to escape newline to continue a string literal through several lines. You also need to swap your ' for "".

Example:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Query> \
  <Where> \
    <And> \
       <Eq> \
          <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
          <Value Type='Text'>PS-ImageSliderRefresh-ImageSlider</Value> \
       </Eq> \
       <Eq> \
          <FieldRef Name='Setting_x0020_Value' /> \
          <Value Type='Note'>Yes</Value> \
       </Eq> \
    </And> \
 </Where> \
 </Query>");
```

And instead of the endless loop with `while (true)` which will fail horribly you could just wrap it in [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval). Like this:

```
function loopScript() {
  setInterval(checkSetting, 5000);
}
```

You also need to call `get_item` with internal name, not field title. I see you use `get_item('Setting Value')` which won't work, since internal name can't contain space.
You can call this in your enumerator loop to see all values if you are unsure:

```
console.log(oListItem.get_fieldValues());
```

Comment: ok that makes sense. the success while loop doesn't seem to function correctly stating that the property or field has not been initialised

Comment: @matt updated answer

Comment: that's great, the field is now accessible as 'Setting_x0020_Value'. When set_item is used it works but on update it doesn't seem to actually change the record? updated solution

Comment: Try calling `oListItem.update();`, and `executeQueryAsync` after that

Comment: is that clientContext.executeQueryAsync(..)?

Comment: Same as you are already using, yes

Comment: ive made the changes but it never seems to run through the async. it changes the value of the field but doesn't refresh the page/hit the onsuccess